# Centering a Table in a Div. Off my 30 pixels

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, centering

I've been playing around with this for days, and just cant get the tables to center. I know you're not supposed to use tables, but in this case I had to store data in it. I can't seem to get the two tables centered no matter what I try.

I've tried removing the parent container, then creating a div around the tables with margin: 0 auto;

It's still always 20-30 pixels off.

http://splendid.ds9design.com/contact/

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: instead of `margin:0 auto;` please try `text-align:center;` just a try.  I'm not sure.

Comment: the tables you want to center are 'SPLENDID & CO' and 'REPRESENTATION' right? If so, I think because their width are 100%. I try to assign width with 600px and add margin: 0 auto; and I think it works

Comment: can you add code here so i can help you

Comment: @murnax http://snag.gy/gauLg.jpg The table looks technically centered, but if you look at the text on the left, its not.

Comment: @sanojlawrence My h1's can be centered using '.ghost2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);' but not my tables

Comment: @DSNYC what do you want to do??

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle. Hope this is just what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/pyhpbwu2/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>This </td>
            <td>is </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>Table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outer{
    background:red;

}
table{
    text-align:center;  
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
td{
    width:100px;
}
```

Setting margin 0px auto; for table does the job.

Comment: I've tried using margin:0px auto; Technically the table is centered but the content isnt. See my screen grab http://snag.gy/gauLg.jpg

Comment: add table{text-align:center; }

Comment: @DSNYC: I have updated the answers and added width to td to make the centering more clear. Check the updated fiddle.